# ArcGIS Arcade Expressions

Tags: arcgis-online, arcade

I'm trying to configure a popup for a polygon feature class so that when clicked attributes from a point feature class show up. For example, if I had 10 clients living in the USA, if I clicked on the USA polygon, the names of those 10 clients would appear in the popup.

So far, I can only get it to display the first value of only the firstname (first and last names are in different fields of the point layer):

```
var intersectLayer =Intersects(FeatureSetByName($map,"Origins"), $feature)

for (var f in intersectLayer){
return f.first_name; " "; f.last_name;
}
```

right now it returns:

```
custom: John
```

but I would like it to return:

```
 John Smith
 Lucy Stone
 Sam Addams
 Butch Cassidy
```

And so on.

Tried gleaning something from this but the code provided doesn't seem to work with my layers:

https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/products/arcgis-online/data-management/pump-up-your-pop-ups-with-arcade-and-the-living-atlas/

Answer (score 2):

Following [this example](https://www.esri.com/arcgis-blog/wp-content/uploads/2019/03/Intersects3.png)
I would recommend modifying your code to return a string with all names like so:

```
var intersectLayer =Intersects(FeatureSetByName($map,"Origins"), $feature)

var customers = ""
for (var f in intersectLayer){
  customers += f.first_name+ " "+ f.last_name + TextFormatting.NewLine;
}
return customers
```

Comment: This actually returns the following error: Execution Error:Cannot assign undeclared variable

Comment: fixed it, just had to add `var` before the first declaration of `customers`.